# Space complexity of a sequential combination of two Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, space-complexity

Let's say I have an Algorithm `A` which is a combination of 2 algorithms `A1` and `A2`.

The algorithm `A` consists of carrying out algorithm `A1` and `A2` one **after another**. The input to algorithm `A` are **2 arrays** of length `m` and `n` respectively.

The goal of algorithm `A1` is to **modify** the 2 arrays. Overall, the **space complexity** of `A1` is `O(m^2 + n^2)`.

Then the modified array is sent to `A2`. And I do not need the auxiliary space occupied by algorithm `A1`. The **space complexity** of `A2` is `O(mn)`.

---

So what should be the overall **space complexity** of the whole algorithm (`A1+A2`)? Should it just be `O(m^2 + n^2 + mn)`?

However, the space occupied by `A1` and `A2` do not happen at the same time and space complexity is all about the worst case space occupied at a point in time. So should it be more appropriate to write `O(max(m^2+n^2,mn))`?

Answer (score 1):

In a sense you are right, the space complexity overall should be `O(m^2 + n^2 + mn)`. However since `mn < max(m^2, n^2)` you can drop it and write is as `O(m^2 + n^2)`.